# How to uninstall Anaconda completely from macOS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, uninstallation

How can I completely uninstall Anaconda from MacOS Sierra and revert back to the original Python? I have tried using `conda-clean -yes` but that doesn't work. I also remove the stuff in `~/.bash_profile` but it still uses the Anaconda python and I can still run the `conda` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Anaconda - How to Safely Uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall)

Comment: haha no way you went to an almost 2 year old post to mark it as duplicate

Comment: how does one uninstall conda if in addition it cannot find the `conda` command but the directory still exists?

Comment: see this: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/  you might have to "macOS
Open the Terminal.app or iTerm2 terminal application, and then remove your entire Anaconda directory, which has a name such as anaconda2, anaconda3, or ~/opt. Enter rm -rf ~/anaconda3 to remove the directory.
" or run `conda install anaconda-clean; anaconda-clean --yes`

Answer (score 353, accepted):

To remove the configs:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Once the configs are removed you can delete the anaconda install folder, which is usually under your home dir:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

Also, the `anaconda-clean --yes` command creates a backup in your home directory of the format `~/.anaconda_backup/<timestamp>`. Make sure to delete that one also.

---

**EDIT (v5.2.0)**: Now if you want to clean all, you will also have to delete the two last lines added to your `.bash_profile`. They look like:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/ody/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Here is an [official link to Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall) for more information.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/anaconda2` is for Mac. For Windows–In the Control Panel, choose Add or Remove Programs or Uninstall a program, and then select Python 3.6 (Anaconda) or your version of Python.

Comment: I used this solution for anaconda3, and I observe there is an issue: former path declared in file .bash_profile or .bashrc have not been deleted, therefore when I reinstalled anaconda3 in a different folder and I tred to use `conda` command.. it fails, saying `bash: /home/nathan/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does simple `rm` leave that anaconda-clean --yes gets rid of?

Comment: Also, conda 3 backs up your bash profile while installing, so you'll want to merge back in those changes.  If you haven't modified your bash profile then you can just copy.

Comment: Great guide, but with a small typo - the default installation location for Anaconda is the `root` folder, not the home folder. Thus, `rm -rf ~/anaconda3` will fail silenty, i.e., run without actually deleting anything. The correct command is  `sudo rm -rf /anaconda3` or  `sudo rm -rf /anaconda2` depending on the Anaconda version installed.

Comment: I had to delete from the /opt folder in the root directory. Somehow it din't get removed when I used rm -rf ~/anaconda.

Steps I used are 
  Open Finder. 
  Press Command+Shift+G to open the dialogue box. 
  Input the following in search box : /opt
  Delete anaconda.

Comment: my conda command still works despite following these instructions...why?!

Comment: why do I get this ```$ anaconda-clean --yes
-bash: anaconda-clean: command not found```?

Comment: I don't know why but just in case someone is suffering like me for some reason it was in this location `/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/opt/` so I did `/Users/brandBrandoParetoopareto/opt/miniconda3`

Comment: how do you do the first command if the `conda` command is not found?

Comment: I have followed these instructions line by line, but I am still getting an odd behaviour after reinstallation. Anaconda Navigator won't launch spyder and won't recognize that I have a more recent version installed (from terminal, via `conda`), compared to what it says on the GUI. If launched from the command line, I get a `/Users/massimopinto/opt/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3:  4379 Illegal instruction: 4  /Users/massimopinto/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"`

Comment: if conda is broken, which is usually why you'd want to do this, this may not work if the environment cannot solve.  happened to me.  the solution @gogasca proposed is better.

Comment: @CharlieParker In the current version(at least as of 11/2020), `anaconda-clean` doesn't work. Use `conda clean -a` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It's rather funny that you need to install another package to remove anaconda. For me, it is in the opt folder. It was neither from home or root. And yes, don't forget to remove it from the path in the .bash_profile.

Comment: As @gogasca mentioned, you also need to delete 3 more folders: rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum

Comment: I followed your instructions and I still have some files in ~/opt/anaconda3 . What about them? Should I just delete the folder?

Comment: ‍‍‍‍`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /`

Comment: I did `which python` to find where the anaconda installation was located

Comment: For mac users you also need to remove lines from `.zshrc` `.bash_profile` and folders from `/opt/anaconda3`

Comment: You need to activate conda first: "conda activate" and then do "anaconda-clean --yes"

Comment: If you are getting `‍‍‍‍Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve.` like @Dr.jacky, first do `conda install anaconda`. It will fix dependencies and you will be able to install `anaconda-clean`

Comment: I hope all the people copying and pasting appreciate what a misplaced space will do to their rm -rf commands!

Answer (score 69):

To uninstall Anaconda open a terminal window:

1. Remove the entire **anaconda** installation directory:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

2. Edit `~/.bash_profile`  and remove the anaconda directory from your `PATH` environment variable.

**Note:** You may need to edit `.bashrc` and/or `.profile` files instead of `.bash_profile`

3. Remove the following hidden files and directories,  which may have been created in the home directory:

   - `.condarc`
   - `.conda`
   - `.continuum`

Use:

```
rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum
```

Comment: Note to newbies: may need to edit .bashrc and/or .profile instead

Comment: As DeltaIV stated above; this will fail. At least did so for me:

"Great guide, but with a small typo - the default installation location for Anaconda is the root folder, not the home folder. Thus, rm -rf ~/anaconda3 will fail silenty, i.e., run without actually deleting anything. The correct command is sudo rm -rf /anaconda3 or sudo rm -rf /anaconda2 depending on the Anaconda version installed."

Comment: I needed to remove coda-related entries in ~/.bash_profile
I replaced the coda stuff in ~/.bash_profile with:
# Pyenv initialization
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

Comment: Nice quick simple explanation worked a treat. Just to add, I found anaconda folder in opt folder: ~/opt/Anaconda3, In addition, I needed to update my brew install of python3.11 with "brew install python3" in order to get pip3 working again, which I needed to update pynvim also. And that was all very painless thankyou @gogasca

Answer (score 20):

***MacOS Big Sur and MacOS High Sierra differ***: the anaconda folder is `~/opt/anaconda3` instead of `~/anaconda3`, according to the comment by jmgonet and answer by Laknath.

### Install the cleaner

```
me@host:~$ conda install anaconda-clean
```

### Activate the 'base' virtual environment

```
me@host:~$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

### Run the cleaner

```
(base) me@host:~$ anaconda-clean --yes
```

### Deactivate the 'base' virtual environment

```
(base) me@host:~$ conda deactivate
```

### Remove the files

```
me@host:~$ rm -rf ~/anaconda3
me@host:~$ rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup
```

### Delete lines added by conda from environment file(s)

Open the `.bashrc` file (and/or `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile`)

```
nano .bashrc
```

Search for `conda` in the .bashrc file (opened in the nano editor):

1. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
2. type `conda`
3. press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Remove everything that looks like it has been added by/for anaconda:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/me/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/me/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/me/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/me/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

This was done on Ubuntu 18.04 and will probably also work on MacOS.

Comment: I've just tested it on a Mac OS Big Sur. It works very well, with only one modification: the Anaconda folder is ~/opt/anaconda3. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @jmgonet! I added the info at the top of my answer, with a credit to you.

Answer (score 18):

In my case (Mac High Sierra) it was installed at ~/opt/anaconda3.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Answer (score 13):

The following line doesn't work?

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
```

You should know where your anaconda3(or anaconda1, anaconda2) is installed. So write

```
which anaconda
```

output

```
output: somewhere
```

Now use that somewhere and run:

```
rm -rf somewhere
```

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal and remove your entire Anaconda directory, which will have a name such as “anaconda2” or “anaconda3”, by entering the following command: `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`. Then remove conda with command `conda uninstall` see https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-uninstall.html.

Comment: When running `conda uninstall` I get `CondaValueError: Value error: no package names supplied,
       try "conda remove -h" for more details`

Comment: write echo $PATH in your terminal to check if there is some reference to anaconda, if there is use export PATH="/path/you/want/to/keep"

Answer (score 3):

None of these solutions worked for me. Turns out I had to remove all the hidden files that you can reveal with `ls -a` My .zshrc file had some anaconda references in it that needed to be deleted

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me:

```
conda remove --all --prefix /Users/username/anaconda/bin/python
```

then also remove from $PATH in .bash_profile

Comment: This is a nice idea, but according to the documentation, this is meant for removal of conda environments. Here is the way Anaconda suggests: [using `anaconda-clean`](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall)

Answer (score 2):

This is one more place that anaconda had an entry that was breaking my python install after removing Anaconda. Hoping this helps someone else.

If you are using yarn, I found this entry in my .yarn.rc file in ~/"username"

python "/Users/someone/anaconda3/bin/python3"

removing this line fixed one last place needed for complete removal. I am not sure how that entry was added but it helped

Answer (score 2):

After performing the very helpful suggestions from both spicyramen & jkysam without immediate success, a simple restart of my Mac was needed to make the system recognize the changes. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` (or `export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` if you have anaconda 3)
to my ~/.bash_profile file, fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. The question is how to _uninstall_ Anaconda, not fix it. What you're suggesting here is a fix for keeping/installing Anaconda, not removing it

Answer (score 0):

unset your ~/.bash_profile's PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME

(ps: when you debug Arduino, you may have set those vars. It would confuse the conda's env)

Answer (score 0):

After running the uninstall commands for Anaconda, miniconda3 was still showing up in the path.  Ultimately this is what worked for me:

With terminal open (I use zsh)

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

Delete the contents, save, exit terminal, and reopen.

This solved the eternal conda issue for me, finally!

Answer (score -4):

The official instructions seem to be here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

but if you like me that didn't work for some reason and for some reason your conda was installed somewhere else with telling you do this:

```
rm -rf ~/opt
```

I have no idea why it was saved there but that's what did it for me.

---

This was useful to me in fixing my conda installation (if that is the reason you are uninstalling it in the first place like me): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902863/1601580 that ended up fixing it for me. Not sure why conda was acting weird in the first place or installing things wrongly in the first place though...

Comment: The `~/opt/` folder could include other installation folders as Homebrew, so you can't remove all the folders inside it.