# JupyterLab in Homebrew-installed Anaconda fails to start kernel, looks for old install

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, homebrew-cask

I was hoping someone could help me understand why JupyterLab fails to spin up a kernel on my system.

#### Background

I'm working on macOS High Sierra.  I used to have Anaconda installed via the Mac OS installer in the default location in my home folder  (`$HOME/anaconda`). Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos?rq=1) I uninstalled Anaconda.

I reinstalled Anaconda from the Homebrew Cask (placing `export PATH=/usr/local/anaconda3/bin:"$PATH"` in my `.bashrc`).

#### The Problem

Now when I

- run `jupyter-lab`,
- create a new notebook, and
- select a Python 3 kernel,

the process fails with the following output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1543, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1107, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1099, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 315, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 148, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/anaconda/bin/python': '~/anaconda/bin/python'`

I'd already removed all references to `$HOME/anaconda` (my old install location) from my environment (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`), so I can't figure out where the reference is being picked up.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4363) for the Jupyter project.  The basic solution:

- run `jupyter kernelspec list` to see if it points to the correct Python install

  - if not, remove the folder `~/Library/Jupyter`
  - re-run `jupyter kernelspec list`

This should rebuild the directory and give output like

`Available kernels:
  python3    /usr/local/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`

which is the proper location for the Homebrew install of Anaconda.