# Deleting Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to delete Anaconda following [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) suggestion:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

However, when I do that, I get:

```
Backup directory: /Users/santanna_santanna/.anaconda_backup/2018-04-17T215007
Error: Unable to move /Users/santanna_santanna/.continuum
```

Any suggestion on how can I go forward deleting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete anaconda ou have just to delete the path "directory" of Anaconda and then remove the line on the file `~/.bashrc` that prepends the anaconda bin directory to your $PATH environment variable.

Deleting the anaconda directory should remove the Anaconda, but it's recommanded  to remove this line from your setup script too.