# Cannot run anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I just installed anaconda and I have udpated the PATH variable.

However, I cannot run any conda related commands.

Every time I run a command starting with "conda" I get the following error.

Can anyone help?

I am using macOs High Sierra 10.13.6.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/path.py", line 18, in <module>
from urllib.request import url2pathname
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 2585, in <module>
from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /anaconda3/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 112, in main
from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 18, in <module>
from .common.io import timeout
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 24, in <module>
from .path import expand
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/common/path.py", line 21, in <module>
from urllib import unquote, url2pathname  # NOQA
ImportError: cannot import name 'unquote'
```

Comment: It looks like [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7130)

Comment: @erip in that link the solution is to rename a library, in my case I have to rename "/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO" . I am not sure this would be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall something similar when I first ran Anaconda on my Mac as well. I believe I solved it by doing two things:

1. Uninstalling Anaconda ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos))
2. Reinstalling Anaconda (potentially in a different location, say, under your User home)

I think in the process of installation my PATH pointed finally to a different location than the Conda/Python install.

Comment: I cannot run those commands to uninstall. I get the same error!

Comment: Ah! Then you may have to do it the long way: https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-a-mac