# anaconda2 still shows up in home directory after sudo rm -rf

Tags: bash, macos, anaconda

I tried to uninstall anaconda2 and thought I was successful since conda didn't show up in the command line anymore.

However, when I use

```
locate anaconda2
```

The directory still shows up in `$HOME` even though when I try to cd into anaconda2, the response is that anaconda2 no longer exists?

Comment: check these once : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.stackexchange.com https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124757/how-to-update-linux-locate-cache

Comment: In which directory are you when launching locate?

Answer (score 0):

You have all information in this [official documentation](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/).

To uninstall anaconda like you want, you can do:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes

rm -rf ~/anaconda3
rm -rf ~/.anaconda_backup
```

And finally clean your `~/.bash_profile` file from something which would look like:

```
# added by AnacondaX Y.Z.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/sfish/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```