# Anaconda Navigator does not open

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda *(which failed a few times)* and removed it again. Then installed Miniconda and after several rounds succeeded. In Terminal 'condo list'gives a result.

However, I cannot open the Anaconda Navigator.
I would like to start using Spyder. Spyder is not found in Terminal.

I checked other questions on Stack Overflow about this but nothing seems to work.

```
(base) 192:~ lsluyser$ sudo anaconda-navigator
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I use a Mac Ox 10.9 and Python 3.7.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `anaconda-navigator` is not included with Miniconda. It seems possible that you may not have uninstalled Anaconda completely. Could you include the steps that you took in your uninstallation of Anaconda here?

You may want to try using installing and running `conda-clean` using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182997).

Comment: Maybe this will help, run `conda update conda` and then `conda update --all`

Comment: It may be that I am a step further without uninstalling Anaconda. I updated conda and installed wing101. I am not sure if it all works as it should but for now: thank you for your help and encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

I too suffered the same multiple installation sequence as you mentioned on a Windows 10 machine.
Finally I removed a file named ".condarc" left over due to the incorrect uninstall. 
The next installation of [anaconda](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2018.12-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg) was successful in launching anaconda-navigator 
but on a Mac with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed I faced no such issues.Tip:"."Dot files are hidden on a Mac

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, I have Windows 7 installed as my OS.

Simple solution:

- Uninstall Anaconda
- Reinstall downloading the latest version
- Before
  opening the GUI, open the Conda Prompt & update all packages:

  `conda update --all`
- Now Open the GUI.

It worked for me.