# Not sure if Anaconda is completely removed

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda, uninstallation

I am fairly new to Python and used Anaconda a few years ago on my Macbook. Now I want to uninstall Anaconda as I have no need for it and want to learn Python (and use Pycharm) from scratch. 
So far, I have followed the instructions on this post: [How to uninstall Anaconda completely from macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos)

But I don't understand the following instruction:

"Now if you want to clean all, you will also have to delete the two last lines added to your .bash_profile. They look like:
`export PATH="/Users/ody/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

Can someone explain what this means? I have Terminal open, what am I supposed to be typing?

I don't even really understand what I'm typing in Terminal so if you could explain as simply as possible that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file in your home directory called `.bash_profile` and when Anaconda installs, it (usually) adds some code to it. Fortunately such code should be indicated by something like

`# Added by Anaconda`

or

`# Contents within this block are managed by conda init`

The instruction is telling you to edit this file to remove any Anaconda-related lines. The idea that they are the necessarily going to be the last two lines in the file is misleading. That completely depends on whether you or programs you have installed subsequently have also manipulated the file.

On a side-note, PyCharm is compatible with Conda environments, so you may still want to consider installing [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) to manage the environments for your PyCharm projects.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation :) so in order to carry out those instructions, how do I access the .bash_profile and edit the file?

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths try googling "how to edit .bash_profile"

Comment: So I've used the nano .bash_profile command and removed everything Anaconda related (there were three chunks). I saved and exited Terminal. Now when I run  ```echo $PATH```, there is no sign of Anaconda. I assume that means I've succeeded in completely removing Anaconda?

Comment: @mathsStudentstudyingmaths you've at least followed all the directions that others have indicated. Personally, I've never done it so I can't affirm.