# How to completely remove all traces of python/conda and reinstall it?

Tags: python, macos, installation, anaconda

I had a good python environment, which got wrecked by MacOS updated which broke Anaconda. I reinstalled Anaconda, but it's still a bit of a mess, where some python kernels for Jupyter Notebooks aren't found, and the system tries to find Python in anaconda3 folders which no longer exist. I tried to fix it which might have made it even messier.

Is there a way I can uninstall everything related to anaconda/python, so that I can just reinstall python3 from scratch?

Comment: Is the [official documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) not enough? _which got wrecked by MacOS updated which broke Anaconda._ Can you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Anaconda completely from macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos)

Answer (score 0):

First look into your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` and remove all traces of Anaconda from there (and check the paths).
Check where `which python` leads and if its softlink, check to what it points.