# Trouble updating to Anaconda Navigator 1.10.0 (MacOS)

Tags: python, anaconda

My Anaconda Navigator (v1.9.12) has been prompting me to upgrade to 1.10.0. Only problem is, when I click "yes" on the update prompt (which should close the navigator and update it), nothing happens.

No problem, I thought. I ran

> conda update anaconda-navigator

in the terminal. To no avail (and yes, I read the doc online and ran "conda deactivate" beforehand), same with

> conda install anaconda-navigator=1.10

Both ran for a while, but the desktop navigator is still on the old version. One thing to note: the `Looking for incompatible packages` line was taking way too long (hours with no notable progress), so I ctrl-c'ed out. But I ran these commands again they managed to finish running.

Now I'm out of ideas, would anyone know what I can do to go through with the update? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I fixed the issue by reinstalling anaconda entirely. I guess my anaconda was completely broken. It wasn't even able to properly install anaconda-clean...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having completely the same issue (same Navigator version on macOS). I think I have spent several hours of all possible solution and nothing helped.

The only solution that worked was to uninstall and install again. The environment setup remains the same so there is nothing to lose (but still it is strange thought)

I was following the process from the answer from this question: [How to uninstall Anaconda completely from macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos)

Comment: Thanks, seems I wasn't the only one! If you wouldn't mind, could you add a detail or two about how you went about doing the uninstall and install? Because I did them in a hacky way and broke my environments in the process, so the information might be useful to others...

Answer (score 30):

The solution is in the documentation of the update itself:

...
-Fixed bug with Navigator Updater tool:
The bug was a part of the 1.9.12 release, so user will not be able to update from 1.9.12 to 1.10.0 through this tool. You will need to use the terminal or install 1.10.0 from our official website.
...

Therefore you have to open anaconda prompt and run the following lines consecutively:

```
conda deactivate
```

*enter*

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

*enter*

Comment: Useful to know that this was a bug in 1.9.12. This process worked well.

Comment: It might be useful to know that this bug is also present on Windows version, and can be solved in the same way - Thanks!

Comment: useful additional details to the answer provided earlier by @Dim_iliop

Comment: I had this bug on the windows version.  This answer worked for me.

Comment: I had to use this method to update from windows version of anaconda navigator (v1.9.12).  For those who, like me, didn't know what anaconda prompt was, you can find and run it by searching in the "start" menu for windows (or whatever its called these days)

Comment: How does one "open anaconda prompt" (new MacOS user)?

Answer (score 12):

If you prefer, you may update Navigator manually.

Open the Anaconda prompt (terminal on Linux or macOS):

Run this command to deactivate conda:

> conda deactivate

Then run this command to update Navigator:

> conda update anaconda-navigator

Had the same problem, worked on me.

Comment: I did indeed run this command. Twice. It seems I'm missing something (probably silly) ...?

Comment: did you run conda deactivate first?

Comment: I set conda up so that I'm not in a conda environment by default when I open up a terminal, so I didn't but I don't think it matters...?

Comment: @Jeffery I think it would matter. Your accepted answer is to uninstall and install again, which essentially is deactivating (and more) before running a fresh install (i.e. updating++).

Comment: @goldfishalpha I just meant that in my particular case typing "conda deactivate" is redundant. But I did try typing it first too.

Answer (score 2):

How I fixed this problem is by the following steps!

1. Open the anaconda navigator in admin mode.
2. Try to click the update notice again.

Then I updated my anaconda navigator successfully.

Comment: I cannot test this anymore, but if other people were able to use this successfully let us know !

Comment: This works for me on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I was stucked in the version 1.9.12 and what worked for me was:

1. Run Anaconda Prompt (Administrator mode)
2. Run the command: conda install anaconda-navigator=2.2.0
3. Run the command: conda update --all