# Anaconda Navigator(version 1.9.12) not upgrading in Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.8

The Anaconda Navigator that I am using is version 1.9.12. Whenever I open the Navigator(run as Administrator), a pop-up comes that asks for upgrade with the following message:

```
There's a new version of Anaconda Navigator available. We strongly recommend you to upgrade.

If you click yes, Anaconda Navigator will close and then the Anaconda Updater will start. 

Do you wish to update to Anaconda Navigator 1.10.0 now?
(You will be prompted to elevate privileges)

No   Yes
```

Once I click the 'Yes' button, the pop-up goes off and nothing will happen(Navigator UI stays there). I tried alternative ways that are mentioned in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144561/anaconda-navigator-does-not-update-packages). I tried the following commands in Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

I ran the Anaconda Prompt as administrator. Once the command is run, the process gets stuck at 'resolving the environments'. It may be noted that Python 3.8 is the version that I am running. The Python programs and all its modules are all running fine. Just that I want to upgrade the Navigator.

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer from the [another StackOverflow post, but for MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468858/trouble-updating-to-anaconda-navigator-1-10-0-macos).  Apparently there's a bug in the Anaconda Updater tool that is fixed in the 1.10 update, but as a catch 22, you can't use the updater to update the software to fix the bug that prevents you from updating the software ([as described in the release notes](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/release-notes/#october-19-2020)).

So what I did was go to the Windows menu and open the Anaconda Powershell Prompt(Anaconda3) and at the prompt enter:

```
conda deactivate
```

then after that is done enter the following:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

then just like a pip install it shows you what needs to be updated, you indicate at the prompt, yes (enter y) and it installs.

good luck!

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks! My version info:  1.9.12-py38_0 --> 2.0.3-py38_0

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the same problem. Windows 10 64bit Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043, Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12

Try

```
conda install anaconda-navigator=2.0.1
```

Worked for me.

After that updated to Anaconda Navigator 2.2.0 (last version) via start GUI menu.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The other suggested solution using the deactivate command followed by the conda update anaconda-navigator failed in my case; it said the process ran out of memory. (I also closed all other applications as a precaution)

Answer (score 0):

After trying different suggested solutions on StackOverflow, this is what eventually worked for me (I am running a Windows 10 Home 21H1 on a 64-bit machine):

1. Exit Anaconda Navigator
2. From Windows Start, launch Anaconda Powershell Prompt (miniconda)
3. At the command line prompt, enter:

   ```
   conda install anaconda
   ```
4. At this point, I tried `conda update anaconda-navigator`, but got the error `PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix <\path\to\package>`:
5. At the command line prompt, enter the following:

   ```
   conda install --prefix <\path\to\package> anaconda-navigator
   conda update anaconda-navigator
   ```