# Trouble updating to Anaconda Navigator 1.10.0 (Windows) - stuck on Solving environment

Tags: anaconda, conda

Anaconda Navigator does not upgrade after selecting the prompt to do so
[image]

Apparently this is a known issue ([Trouble updating to Anaconda Navigator 1.10.0 (MacOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468858/trouble-updating-to-anaconda-navigator-1-10-0-macos)) but the solution there

```
conda deactivate
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

doesn't work for me.
Other posts suggested first running

```
conda update --all
```

which I did, apparently successfully, but when I go back to try the update above  I still get stuck on Solving environment:
[image]

It's been stuck there for more than 12 hours, so I think it's safe to conclude it's not going to get unstuck.

Any suggestions?
Could the "InvalidArchiveError" related to the pytorch archive (see image) be an issue (I wouldn't have thought so)?