# dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pycharm

> vincens@VMAC: python3
> dyld: Library not
> loaded:/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>
> Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
> Reason: image not found
> [1]    25278 abort      python3

python3 env is not used when I update my Mac to the latest version. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 31):

This worked for me with the same issue.

Check if you have multiple Python3.x versions installed.  In my case I had `Python3.6` and `Python3.9` installed. `brew uninstall python3` did not remove `Python3.6` completely.

I was able to call `Python3.9` from Terminal by explicitly running `python3.9` instead of `python3`, which led me to believe the issue was caused by ambiguity in which Python3.x resource was to be used.

Manually deleted `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6` resulted in Python3 running as expected.

*hint:*
It may be sufficient to remove `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6` from your PATH environment variable.

Comment: thanks for the info, was really helpful. :)

Answer (score 14):

Check in the location:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

If you can invoke python3 interpreter from this location without any issues, copy this to

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

I upgraded to macOS Big Sur and had faced the same issue. I was not able to open Python interpreter from terminal and the Python version inside Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6 was also being pointed to Python2.7.

Later, I found python3 in location `/usr/bin/python3` working fine for me. I also tried creating a symlink for *python3* to the above path but didn't work.

Answer (score 12):

That's becuase you have installed both python 3.6 from system library & python3.9 from other source like brew and there are something wrong with the python in lower version. Please manually delete the python within /Library/Frameworks. `sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6` this command works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem on [Step 1 of PyCharm's Create a Django project documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-django-project.html#create%20a%20Django%20project).

I had previously set up Python on my Mac following [these instructions](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac). Can't promise this solution will work for everyone, but maybe if someone's Python was set up similar to mine the following solution that worked for me might help you...

1. Open Terminal
2. `which python3`
3. Copy the directory given to you... (For me it was `/Users/foo/.pyenv/bar/python3`)
4. When creating your new Django project in PyCharm (Professional Edition), set your base directory to the one received from `which python3`
5. Create your project

Answer (score 0):

I had python 3.9 on Mac. I needed to switch to python3.6.

I first install python 3.6.0 (download python-3.6.0-macosx10.6.pkg, then double click and follow installation steps). Then, I had the same error as in your question.

Then I installed python 3.6.5(download python-3.6.5-macosx10.9.pkg, then double click and follow installation steps) and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

My case

1. Deleted Xcode (Maybe some folders are accidentally deleted like `/Library/Frameworks/...`
2. Also installed Python with `anaconda`.

My solution

1. Reinstall Xcode
2. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182997/5737856) to remove `anaconda` then everything works fine