# aws --version error: dyld: Library not loaded:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, python-venv

After recent upgrade to big sur, I am unable to run aws cli on my local machine. I have used the cli for a while without any issue, and Installed it globally on my machine. I get the pop-up error message saying:

> "Python cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer to make sure Python works with this version of macOS. You may need to reinstall the application. Be sure to install any available updates for the application and macOS.
> Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple"

This is followed by `dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python Reason: image not found [1]    83779 abort      aws --version`

I have multiple versions of python installed, from python3.7 to 3.9 I also used venv with python3.9 and then installed the CLI in that environment, however i still get the same error message when i try `aws --version` I know there are posts that looks very similar to mine, however i have tried most of those solutions and nothing works so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878141/dyld-library-not-loaded-system-library-frameworks-corefoundation-framework-ve)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878141/dyld-library-not-loaded-system-library-frameworks-corefoundation-framework-ve