# Python and Jupyter Notebook commands not working after upgrading to MacOS Ventura 13.4

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, dyld, macos-ventura

I deleted XCode and upgraded my MacOS to Ventura 13.4. After these changes, I could not run jupyter notebook with command `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter-notebook`. The error is as follows:

```
dyld[9426]: dyld cache '(null)' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
dyld[9426]: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: <E585A67D-C0DB-448A-2E74-422D61BDC1C1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: tried:
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file), 
 '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file),
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file, no dyld cache),
 '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation' (no such file)
```

I have several Python versions installed as well as Anaconda. If I run However, if I run `python3 -m site` then it gives the same error as above.

Based on the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878141/dyld-library-not-loaded-system-library-frameworks-corefoundation-framework-ve), I tried removing the 3.6 from `/Library/Framworks/Python.framework/Versions` but it didn't work and showed errors as followed.

If I run `jupyter notebook`, it gives error

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I run `jupyter-notebook`, it gives error

```
-bash: /Users/<username>/Library/Python/3.6/bin/jupyter-notebook: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I was thinking it might be a issue related to `PATH`. Is there any method with which I can locate the issue and figure out the solution to solve the issue? Appreciate any help!

Comment: "I tried deleting the Python3.6 by directly removing the folder from /Library/Framworks/Python.framework" Ok so that computer is now hosed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with python and postgres failing to run after upgrading to Ventura. This was fixed by opening XCode and following the prompts to upgrade XCode, which presumably upgraded/fixed various developer dependencies. So try running (or installing) XCode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).