# Modifying .name files when uninstalling anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda

I wanted anaconda to be completely uninstalled from my computer, then possibly reinstall it.

I did what is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos) except that the last two lines on `.bash_profile` do not look like the ones I wish to remove.
I expected it to be clear what I wanted to delete, but it is not (for me at least).
Instead the `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/Tinius/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/Tinius/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/Tinius/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/Tinius/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

Should I remove anything from here? For instance, what is inside the inner-else statement as this is the `\export PATH="/Users/Tinius/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"` part talked about in the link above? If so, do I remove the entire else statement?

### A second question:

Are there any other `.name` files I need to delete or modify to succesfully uninstall anaconda?

I'm sorry if this is completely noobish, but I have been rather lost with installing and uninstalling stuff on the Macbook pro mid 2014. I updated from Mojave to Big Sur today.

Thank you

### Edit

Picture of files in `/Users/myuser`:

[Files and folders screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ7X5.png)

Comment: You should be able to remove everything from _# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer_ to _# <<< conda init <<<_. Did you already run anaconda-clean?

Comment: @AMC Thank you! Yes, I ran anaconda -clean. 
Do you know if there are other files I should delete something from or entirely? I added a screenshot of relevant files and folders from `/users/myuser` to the original post.

Comment: What you shared in the screenshot seems fine, you could always just delete anything which mentions Conda or Anaconda.