# Why is anaconda3 still in `$PATH` after removing respective lines from `~/.bash_profile`?

Tags: path, anaconda

I have uninstalled `anaconda3` according to the [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos/60895064#60895064) by:

1. Installing the cleaner

   `$ conda install anaconda-clean`
2. Activating the 'base' virtual environment

   `$ source ~/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`
3. Running the cleaner

   `(base) $ anaconda-clean --yes`
4. Deactivating the 'base' virtual environment

   `(base) $ conda deactivate`
5. Removing the files

   `$ rm -rf ~/opt/anaconda3`

   `$ rm -rf ~/opt/.anaconda_backup`
6. Deleting all lines added by conda from environment file(s)

Opening my `.bash_profile` file (for others might be `.profile` and/or `.bashrc`)

In my case I deleted these lines:

```
    # >>> conda initialize >>>
    # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
    __conda_setup="$('/home/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        eval "$__conda_setup"
    else
        if [ -f "/home/me/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
            . "/home/me/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        else
            export PATH="/home/me/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
        fi
    fi
    unset __conda_setup
    # <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I quit the iTerm and I have restarted the my *MacOS Catalina 10.15.7* on the next day. But when running `echo $PATH` I still get:

```
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

### What did I do wrong?

I veryfied that I saved the changes to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
# history size
export HISTFILESIZE=1000000
export HISTSIZE=1000000
```