# Cannot install tensorflow-deps for Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, apple-silicon

I'm trying to set-up by Apple Silicon Mac to be able to train tf models using its GPU.

I tried following the [official instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) but I am getting the following error:

```
>>> conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - tensorflow-deps

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/apple/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Not sure if it should matter but I didn't install Miniforge because I already have Anaconda installed comprehensively. Surely, this can't be the reason? (I didn't want to install Miniforge not to mess up my env by having multiple Conda installations).

I did add the "apple" channel in the Navigator manually and the package does seem to be there:

https://anaconda.org/apple/tensorflow-deps

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you use the Anaconda that supports M1 natively as said in here  https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1?

Comment: Not yet, this didn’t exist back then - will check out, thanks a lot 

Comment: You may check my experience here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964800/what-is-the-proper-way-to-install-tensorflow-on-apple-m1-in-2022

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this for a while. The only way I was able to get a successful environment set up was indeed installing conda through mini forge. Based on [this link](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153) I believe this is because of the other packages Anaconda pre-installs that are not ARM compatible.

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182706/how-to-uninstall-anaconda-completely-from-macos) to remove my Anaconda installation. Once that is done the [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) you linked should be successful.