# PATH is not updated when I login

Tags: linux, bash, debian, environment-variables, .profile

I am one of the users of a lab computer. I want *[PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html)* to be:

`PATH=/home/gsamaras/mpich-install/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

instead of this:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

For that reason, I modified *.profile*:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
#if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
#    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
if [ -d "$HOME/mpich-install/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$HOME/mpich-install/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

then I did a `source .profile` and it was OK. However, the next day (when I powered on the pc) and eventually logged into my account, *PATH* was reset. Then I found `/etc/profile`, which seems to be the key file for me, since it has this:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH
```

However, this I think that is going to be executed for *every* user in this machine, not just me, so how should I modify it so that I do not need to source my local .profile every time I log in?

PS - I know the password for sudo.

---

*EDIT*

I can not find any ***.bash_profile*** file:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ find .bash_profile
find: `.bash_profile': No such file or directory
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ find /etc/bash_profile
find: `/etc/bash_profile': No such file or directory
```

Here is my ***.bashrc*** file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    #alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    #alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    #alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# MPI Samaras
if type keychain >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  keychain --nogui -q id_rsa
  [ -f ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh ] && . ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh
  [ -f ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh-gpg ] && . ~/.keychain/${HOSTNAME}-sh-gpg
fi
```

Comment: And what's on your `.bash_profile` ?

Comment: @Thomas I couldn't find one. Check my edit.

Comment: Ok, and a `bashrc` ?

Comment: I thought of posting that too, but it's "big". Edited @Thomas!

Comment: Make a `.bash_profile`, put your path in there.Also it should be in your home directory, not etc ?

Comment: @User112638726 can you make an answer mentioning how exactly this `.bash_profile` would be? About what are you asking me please? :)

Comment: @gsamaras In your question it looks like you are looking for `.bash_profile` in etc instead of your home directory. I was wondering why you would think it was there ?

Comment: @User112638726 I first executed `find` in my home directory and found nothing. Then I thought about `/etc`, just becase there was a profile there (as I mention in my question), nothing more than that.

Comment: Note all files in `/etc/` will apply to all users, so it is not a good place to change places. Instead, just touch a `.bash_profile` in your home directory and add this statement. See also [What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/415403/1983854) for more info.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for the comment. However, this didn't work too, since `.bash_profile` (which I created after the answer from Thomas) seems to not be executed automatically. If I source it, then it will update the `PATH` as expected. Do you have any suggestion? I can't see other from updating something in `/etc/`.

Comment: @User112638726 `.bash_profile`, which I created does not seem to be executed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` file add the following command:

`PATH="/home/gsamaras/mpich-install/bin:$PATH"`

Then execute:

```
. .bashrc
```

from you home directory. Now, check you path (or) logout and login.

Comment: That means I will have to exeucte this EVERY time I login?

Comment: No, that's not needed. It will be automatically loaded when you open you terminal. Just try it.

Comment: That's it. Great first answer. Check how I edited your answer, so that you know pretty much the tools for your next answer. Bravo! :) +1 to your question too!

Answer (score 1):

From the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables):

- Put all global definitions, i.e. ones affecting all users into /etc/profile.
- Insert all personal definitions into ~/.profile
- Create or edit file ~/.bash_profile and include commands:

  ```
  if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
       . ~/.profile
  fi
  ```

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the answer. However, `~/.bash_profile`, which I created does not execute automatically when I login.

Comment: @gsamaras are you sure you're using *bash* and not any other shell?

Comment: According to this(http://stackoverflow.com/a/9911082/2411320) answer, I am using *bash*.

Comment: @gsamaras of course you read this `Of course the above will fail when /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash.` ? It so, it's wierd :/

Comment: Thomas, I got `ls -a /bin/sh
/bin/sh`, thus it's not a symlink, I guess. I also tried the last suggestion from the answer and got same result!

Comment: @gsamaras well I would give you this link to [why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work) but this question is out of my league :)

Comment: Thanks, I read it and appended your suggestion to `.bashrc`. Nothing happened again! The only difference was that when I tried to source it, it would take too long though and I forced a quit. Also, when I opened up the terminal, it would take some time to start. By the way, nice top answer, maybe I will link it to mine's top answer.

Comment: Thomas, your answer didn't solve the problem, but +1 in this answer too for your effort. Merci!